# Potential Question: Does An Old Mac G5 Make A Great BBQ?

Tags: discussion

**Was thinking about putting this as a question (if of humor) on Ask Different**

Just came across this as an alternative recycling option:

[image]

Source: [Macgasm](http://www.macgasm.net/2013/05/20/check-out-this-dude-who-turned-a-g5-into-a-bbq-grill/)

Is this really a viable option (if extreme) & what other recycling methods exist for an old G5 ?

Comment: I don't know that I would cook stuff on a surface with god knows what chemicals...

Comment: @JasonSalaz I totally agree with you.....Insane

Comment: @JasonSalaz It looks like he's put another grate over the side of it. Presumably it is a more reliable grilling surface.

Comment: My guess is the case would warp severely if you put hot coals in it repeatedly. I was under the impression that the G5 / Mac Pro chassis were simply anodized aluminum which wouldn't be more or less harmful than aluminum foil or aluminum pots and pans. I'd want to see a heat sink grill pattern for maximum geek points - that round waffle pattern seems odd for grilling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it makes a "grate" BBQ surface but not a great one.

Also, al-yoo-mini-yum